# ASP.NET MVC SiteMap provider doesn't generate sitemap nodes from attributes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nodes, mvcsitemapprovider

**UPDATE:** *despite of all the text below, the issue was fairly small - the wrong assembly name in the includeAssembliesForScan parameter in the configuration of siteMap. It shouldn't include the ".dll" part.*

I have v. 3.2.2.0 of MvcSiteMapProvider.

As described [here](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/wiki/Defining-sitemap-nodes-in-code), I use attributes to define sitemap nodes in code. But attributed actions aren't generated as nodes. Only nodes are generated that are explicitly defined in the sitemap.

That is my code:

sitemap:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<mvcSiteMap xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xmlns="http://mvcsitemap.codeplex.com/schemas/MvcSiteMap-File-3.0"
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://mvcsitemap.codeplex.com/schemas/MvcSiteMap-File-3.0 MvcSiteMapSchema.xsd"
            enableLocalization="true">

  <mvcSiteMapNode 
        title="$resources:Mvc.sitemap,MainMenuTop_Main" 
        controller="Home" 
        action="Index" 
        key="Home">    

    <mvcSiteMapNode 
            title="$resources:Mvc.sitemap,Account" 
            controller="Account" 
            action="LogOn" 
            clickable="false" 
            key="Account" /> 

  </mvcSiteMapNode>

</mvcSiteMap>
```

home controller:

```
[HttpGet]
[MvcSiteMapProvider.MvcSiteMapNode(
    ParentKey = "Home", 
    Title = "$resources:Mvc.sitemap,MainMenuTop_About")]
public ActionResult About()
{
    return View();
}
```

account controller:

```
[HttpGet]
[MvcSiteMapProvider.MvcSiteMapNode(
    ParentKey = "Account", 
    Title = "$resources:Mvc.sitemap,Register")]
public ActionResult Register()
{
    return View();
}
```

So, these two actions won't become nodes in sitemap. In other words, MvcSiteMapNodeAttribute attribute didn't work. Why?

My siteMap part of web.config:

```xml
<siteMap defaultProvider="MvcSiteMapProvider" enabled="true">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add 
      name="MvcSiteMapProvider" 
      type="MvcSiteMapProvider.DefaultSiteMapProvider, MvcSiteMapProvider"
      siteMapFile="~/Mvc.Sitemap" 
      securityTrimmingEnabled="true" 
      cacheDuration="5" 
      enableLocalization="true" 
      scanAssembliesForSiteMapNodes="true" 
      includeAssembliesForScan="Site2.dll" 
      excludeAssembliesForScan="" 
      attributesToIgnore="visibility" 
      nodeKeyGenerator="MvcSiteMapProvider.DefaultNodeKeyGenerator, MvcSiteMapProvider" 
      controllerTypeResolver="MvcSiteMapProvider.DefaultControllerTypeResolver, MvcSiteMapProvider" 
      actionMethodParameterResolver="MvcSiteMapProvider.DefaultActionMethodParameterResolver, MvcSiteMapProvider" 
      aclModule="MvcSiteMapProvider.DefaultAclModule, MvcSiteMapProvider" 
      siteMapNodeUrlResolver="MvcSiteMapProvider.DefaultSiteMapNodeUrlResolver, MvcSiteMapProvider" 
      siteMapNodeVisibilityProvider="MvcSiteMapProvider.DefaultSiteMapNodeVisibilityProvider, MvcSiteMapProvider" 
      siteMapProviderEventHandler="MvcSiteMapProvider.DefaultSiteMapProviderEventHandler, MvcSiteMapProvider"/>
  </providers>
</siteMap>
```

Comment: I just had a similar problem. Can you tell me how you standard namespace and your assembly name look like? 
In my application they did not match and that was the reason for MvcSiteMap to think it would be inside an Area wich resulted in a wrong Url generation.

Comment: I have the same namespace name and assembly name. But the resources for mvcSiteMapNode titles is located in the Resources namespace (actually it is App_GlobalResources project folder).

Comment: And I have no areas in my ASP.NET MVC application.

Comment: Can it help if I create an area and put all my previous site content into it, and then indicate this area name in all of the MVC SiteMap provider parts (sitemap, action attributes, etc.)?.. But I think it will be too complicated for just making the MVC SiteMap provider work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to ensure you have specified to scan for sitemap nodes in your configuration and also supply the assembly name that your controllers reside in. Note that you only need to give the name of the assembly, not a path to it. The assembly must be referenced from your project.

Note that in v4, your MVC project is now registered automatically by the NuGet package, but if you put your controllers in another assembly, you will need to add your controller assembly to the list (separated by commas).

MvcSiteMapProvider v4 (internal DI):

```
<!-- web.config -->
<appSettings>
    <add key="MvcSiteMapProvider_ScanAssembliesForSiteMapNodes" value="true" />
    <add key="MvcSiteMapProvider_IncludeAssembliesForScan" value="MyAssemblyName" />
</appSettings>
```

MvcSiteMapProvider v4 (external DI):

```
// DI Module (file name varies depending on DI container)
string[] includeAssembliesForScan = new string[] { "MyAssemblyName" };
```

You also need to ensure the ReflectionSiteMapNodeProvider is registered in your configuration.

MvcSiteMapProvider v3:

```
<siteMap defaultProvider="MvcSiteMapProvider" enabled="true">
    <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="MvcSiteMapProvider"
             type="MvcSiteMapProvider.DefaultSiteMapProvider, MvcSiteMapProvider"
             siteMapFile="~/Mvc.Sitemap"
             securityTrimmingEnabled="true"
             cacheDuration="5"
             enableLocalization="true"
             scanAssembliesForSiteMapNodes="true"
             excludeAssembliesForScan=""
             includeAssembliesForScan="MyAssemblyName"
             attributesToIgnore="visibility"
             nodeKeyGenerator="MvcSiteMapProvider.DefaultNodeKeyGenerator, MvcSiteMapProvider"
             controllerTypeResolver="MvcSiteMapProvider.DefaultControllerTypeResolver, MvcSiteMapProvider" 
             actionMethodParameterResolver="MvcSiteMapProvider.DefaultActionMethodParameterResolver, MvcSiteMapProvider"
             aclModule="MvcSiteMapProvider.DefaultAclModule, MvcSiteMapProvider"
             routeMethod=""
             siteMapNodeUrlResolver="MvcSiteMapProvider.DefaultSiteMapNodeUrlResolver, MvcSiteMapProvider"
             siteMapNodeVisibilityProvider="MvcSiteMapProvider.DefaultSiteMapNodeVisibilityProvider, MvcSiteMapProvider"
             siteMapProviderEventHandler="MvcSiteMapProvider.DefaultSiteMapProviderEventHandler, MvcSiteMapProvider"/>
    </providers>
</siteMap>
```

Comment: I have v. 3.2.2.0 of MvcSiteMapProvider. I also have the same "siteMap" part of web.config as yours except of assembly name (I update my question to put my siteMap configuration there). My controllers reside in the same assembly as my site. But again the nods that aren't explicitly defined in the mvc.sitemap file aren't generated as nods. In other words, MvcSiteMapNodeAttribute attribute didn't work. I try to update MvcSiteMapProvider to v.4 - maybe then it will work.

Comment: Your assembly name should not include the exension ".dll". It must be the same as what is configured as "Assembly name" field in project properties on the Application tab.

Comment: I fix the assembly name. But another problem appears - at least the root node must be defined in the mvc.sitemap file, because of the attributed action method just without ParentKey parameter of attribute isn't recognized as the root node. How to define the root node with only attribute MvcSiteMapNodeAttribute - what parameters are minimum required?

Comment: In addition, I use only Title and Key for my supposed root (parent for all others) node, but it seems it isn't enough.

Comment: By default, the root node must be defined in the .sitemap file. In v4, you can specify to ignore the root node with MvcSiteMapProvider_IncludeRootNodeFromSiteMapFile="false". If you don't intend to use XML to configure your SiteMap, set the MvcSiteMapProvider_EnableSiteMapFile="false". As far as I know, v3 didn't have a way to configure it without your root node in XML, but that is the only node that is required to be there.

Comment: Can you help me with [another one question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20285752/how-to-create-grouping-and-clickable-nodes-from-single-action), please?