# How to create grouping and clickable nodes from single action simultaneously?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mvcsitemapprovider

I have controller Account and its method LogOn. How to create sitemap like this:

```
-Account // non clickable, just grouping
--Log On // clickable
```

? If I use site map in the form of XML-file (mvc.sitemap) I can write like this:

```xml
<mvcSiteMapNode 
    title="Account" 
    controller="Account" 
    action="LogOn" 
    clickable="false" 
    key="AccountGroup" >

    <mvcSiteMapNode 
        title="Log On" 
        controller="Account" 
        action="LogOn"
        key="LogOn" />
</mvcSiteMapNode>
```

But I want to do it with only MvcSiteMapNodeAttribute attribute. However, only one such attribute can be applied to the method. I also don't want to use some dummy method to create just grouping node.

For now I have only one approach - create grouping nodes in the XML mvc.sitemap file, and clickable nodes - with MvcSiteMapNodeAttribute attribute. But I want to escape to write site map by hands as far as possible. Can it be done without grouping nodes in the XML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using v4, you can apply multiple MvcSiteMapNodeAttributes to a single action method.

```
//
// GET: /Account/LogOn
[MvcSiteMapNodeAttribute(Title = "Account", ParentKey = "Home", Key = "AccountGroup", Clickable = false)]
[MvcSiteMapNodeAttribute(Title = "Log On", ParentKey = "AccountGroup", Key = "LogOn")]
public ActionResult LogOn()
{
    return View();
}
```

You can also put the grouping node on the controller class if that is what you prefer (even in v3).

```
[MvcSiteMapNodeAttribute(Title = "Account", ParentKey = "Home", Action = "LogOn", Key = "AccountGroup", Clickable = false)]
public class AccountController
{

     // Implementation here
}
```

Comment: Hmm... it seems to me that the first variant works also in my version 3.2.2.0. And for the second remark, the second variant also works for me, but except of Action named parameter - it just doesn't present in the attribute constructor even for the class-level attribute.

Comment: You might also have to specify Controller explicitly. I am not sure how it was done in your version, but I know the way the attributes are reflected has changed quite a bit. v4 has many bug fixes that you could benefit from, but does take some work to upgrade to. https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/wiki/Upgrading-from-v3-to-v4